# Plotting a graph using the values generated

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have created a queue buffer and need to generate a plot of the number of packets in the queue over time. I am a beginner and cannot find ways to store the number of packets in the buffer at each time after executing the while loop and therefore when I run the program it just gives a plot of the number of packets in queue at the termination of loop. Can anyone please suggest a way of getting a plot of 'Q' over time at every stage of the execution of loop. I have provided the code below.

```
%Queue Buffer%
Q=0;%queue length
s=10;%Number of packets departing from queue at each time
Q2=0;%New queue length
Ti=0;%Number of times packets arrive
while Ti<=20
   Q=0+Q2;
   a= randi(32,1,1);
   a1=a-s;
   a2=Q+a1;
   Q2= max(0,a2);
   Ti=Ti+1;
end
    t=0:1:100;
    plot (t,Q,'o')
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy way

```
Q = [];
%For loop start
Q = [Q Q2];
%End for loop
```

Better way

```
Q = zeros(1,101); %Since you are plotting from 0:1:100. (Default step is 1, so 0:1:100 = 0:100)
cnt = 1;
%For loop start
Q(cnt) = Q2;
cnt = cnt + 1;
%End for loop
```

Comment: For the easy way (or wrong way). With Q = [], you are declaring Q as an array and Q = [Q Q2] means that the new value of Q is the old array plus the value of Q2 so Q is growing in size by one each turn (time expensive procedure). Q = zeros(1,101) is an array of zeros of 1 line and 101 columns, or a column vector. Then you say Q(cnt) = Q2, vector seat number cnt is to contain value Q2 And in the end you use the plot function to plot the x (0:100) coordinates and y (Q) coordinates in the graph. Btw in MATLAB the first slot in an array or vector is 1 not 0. Hope this helps.